# RestKit 2nd-level object mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'll try to explain how I want the mapping done:

TOP lvl json object contains Players object which is an array of `Player` objects
each `Player` object contains an array, I want each of those objects in the array to be of an `Event` object (custom object).

now since I have a mapping of the `Player` object and i'm getting the array filled, tho instead of `Event` objects(which is what I want), i'm getting `NSDictionary` objects. thing is that I do have a mapping of my `Event` class. my issue is getting the **RestKit** to map these into the array.
I've tried adding responseDescriptors of an `Event` class tho i've had no luck.

Here is the `Player` object mapping

```
 RKObjectMapping* playerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Player class]];
    [playerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                        ...more here              
                                           @"activeEvents" : @"activeEvents"
                                                         }];
```

here is the request method

```
 NSURL *taskURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kAppWebApiURLPath];

    // Set object manager with base url
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:taskURL];
    objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

    [objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Authorization" value:kAppWebAPIKey];
    [objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];

RKRequestDescriptor * requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider inverseLoginMapping]  objectClass:[LoginInfo class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

RKResponseDescriptor *playersResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider playerMapping] method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"players" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:playersResponseDescriptor];

NSLog(@"%@",loginInfo.iOSDeviceToken);
[objectManager postObject:loginInfo path:kAppWebApiLoginPath parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
 {}...
```

Update, I now need one step further of mapping, My player object contains an array of events which I successfully mapped using

```
[playerMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"activeEvents" mapping:[MappingProvider eventMapping]];
```

yet now each of those Event objects contains an array of Players, so its like Players -> Events -> Players.

Here is the Mapping for both Event and Player objects :

```
RKObjectMapping* eventMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Event class]];

    [eventMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{

              @"stuffhere" : @"stuffz"                              
                                                       }];


    RKObjectMapping* playerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Player class]];
    [playerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                        @"name": @"name",
                                                        @"activeEvents" : @"activeEvents"
                                                        }];
    [eventMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"activeEvents/players" mapping:playerMapping];
```

now I don't get a recursive function, but how do I state in code to make that relationship
mapping of the json array to assign to my local array property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `@"activeEvents" : @"activeEvents"` from the mapping and replace it with:

```
[playerMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"activeEvents" mapping:eventMapping];
```

You should also only have one response descriptor because the data is nested.

Comment: it does give me an Event object tho all its properties are null. any ideas ? WARNING: Failed mapping nested object: (null)

Comment: That would indicate your `eventMapping` was wrong. You would need to show it and the JSON...

Comment: yep I was off by a little. fixed it and got it running :), thx dude. party on wain :P

Comment: wain, another question if you will. every player has an active event yet every active event also has players in it, I tried adding the solution you gave me to also get an array of players yet I get an infinite loop between event mapping and player mapping calling each other. any ideas ?

Comment: Don't use `[MappingProvider ...` - create the mappings at the same time so they can directly refer to each other without recursive method calls

Comment: ok I resolved the recursive method calls as you can see in my updated question(added the new code), tho now how can I specify that: mapping :     [eventMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"activeEvents/players" mapping:playerMapping];
to assign to my local array object ?

Comment: The mappings can reference each other, because the data being processed will limit the depth of recursion. Your issue was just with method calls as there is nothing to limit the depth...

Comment: yea but how can I assign the mapping to my local object ?

Comment: Local object? Your mapping is fine, you just need to create the mapping in a single method rather than having each method calling the other...